# How To Scale Images and Background In Table Layout and How To AutoFit Columns

Tags: android, scrollview, scale, tablelayout

I have been trying to write a bookshelf app in Android using the ScrollView and TableLayout. I have referred to other questions on this website concerning the process of making a bookshelf, but I could not find a specific answer to my question. First of all, I want to know how to scale images that I have passed into the TableLayout. I have tried several methods such as shrinkColumns, stretchColumns, scaleX, scaleY. However, none of them seem to work or solve the problem. There is one book that is cut on the edge of the screen, and under all circumstances of stretching and scaling, that book is always cut off. I want to know if there is a way to autofit the number of columns to ensure that it autofits on all screen sizes and orientations. There is a a way to do this in GridView, but I am not able to do this in TableLayout. The images are also scaled in, and I want to scale them out. Please help!

MainActivity.java

```
package org.example.mylayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int numRow = 8;
        int numCol = 15;

        TableLayout tblLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);

        for(int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
            HorizontalScrollView HSV = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
            HSV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(this);


            TableRow.LayoutParams myParams = (new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            myParams.rightMargin = 50;


            tblRow.setLayoutParams((new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));


            tblRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row);

            for(int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                imageView.setLayoutParams(myParams);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.book);
                tblRow.addView(imageView,j);
            }

            HSV.addView(tblRow);
            tblLayout.addView(HSV, i);
        }
    }
}`
```

activity_main

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView" >



    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:ignore="ScrollViewSize">


    </TableLayout>       

</ScrollView>
```

The final emulated version has the right book cut off and a background of the bookshelf which is extremely scaled. How do I fix this? Thanks a lot!